# how to create family of products in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have 1 shared class library A, amongst many client projects, B,C,D, E...etc

I want to be able to create new versions of A, and in turn generate new versions of B,C,D etc..

i.e.

I have version 1 of A....so I get B1,C1,D1,E1...

I create (somehow) version 2 of A....I want to build in B2,C2,D2,E2...

and still have B1,C1,D1....

I obviously can, whenever I create a new version of A, go through all my projects and creating new versions of them, referencing A2, rather than A1..

that's a very long boring process, it would be nice if TFS would somehow know to build multiple versions of a project and you referenced a family of libraries, not a single instance of it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you checked the shared libraries in to TFS and manager the version control of it.

It's not a recommend way, there are multiple downsides such as it's never exactly clear which projects are using which versions of which assemblies. It's a maintenance nightmare. For example if you need to debug a issue and need B1,C2 ,D1, E2.

Suggest you use **Nuget** to handle the shared libraries between different projects in TFS. You should compile your code, package it in Nuget and publish it. For multiple projects you can upgrade their nuget references when appropriate, or stick with the older versions if they need to. If you need to reference a known-good, stable version, you just make sure your project is configured to pull a specific version from NuGet.  More details please refer this tutorial in MSDN: [Get started with NuGet Package Management in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-nuget)

Build multiple versions of a project and referenced a family of libraries, not a single instance of it in a single build is also not support in TFS.

Comment: the issue would be with application D....then we just need to know if it's D1, D2 or D3....so I'm not concerned with the maintenance problem....what I'm after really is given a set of N apps and m versions of some shared component, automatically build (and test bla bla) the NxM products...I can of course do it maunually, I don't think Nuget works in this context, because I want an update to a version of the shared module to trigger a build of the clients.

Comment: @user2088029 It's not able to automatically build the NXM products in one go. You could  only reference  a single instance, not  a family of libraries. There is no such setting or variable  in TFS build.For this situation, you have to manually run N builds.